# Nodejs AWS Lambda failing due to Runtime exited with error: signal: aborted (core dumped)

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a lambda in a step-function working for a while , but now it suddenly started to fail due to this error:

```
 Error: Runtime exited with error: signal: aborted (core dumped)\",\"errorType\":\"Runtime.ExitError
```

I have increased the memory for this lambda to maximum 10240, and also added a retry strategy to re-run the lambda on  error , but once this error shows up it won't go away even on retries:

```
                transformer:
                  Type: Task
                  Resource: !GetAtt transformer.Arn
                  Retry:
                    - ErrorEquals: ["States.ALL"]
                      IntervalSeconds: 3
                      MaxAttempts: 10
                      BackoffRate: 1
                  Comment: Transforms a chunk of data by inserting assets, and then uploads the result to an image bucket.
                  End: true
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some investigation I've found the cause for this issue and it was because of a very big array of promises for `await Promise.all([])` call with s3 operations in it . So basically AWS wanted us to slow down  a bit . I've resolved the issue by chunking the big array of promises into a smaller one.

Answer (score 2):

Increasing Lambda memory from 512mb ram to 1024mb helped in resolving this issue for me.